# Access oModel data in Extended Fiori controller

Tags: html, sapui5, sap-fiori

How can I access the data of a oModel inside an extended Fiori Controller?

I'm trying the following, but with no success:

> this.getView().getModel()

This return a object, buit When I try do acess .getData() it is null...

I'm extending the MM_PO_APV app, and S3 controller.

Thank for your support.

Comment: Can you also post a context of where you have `this.getView().getModel()` in place and how exactly you are making use of it ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's still relevant by try to access the data like this:

`sap.ui.getCore().getModel().oData;`